# With character or sign

Tags: abbreviations, typography, symbols, alphabet

Is there a character or sign for *'with'*, similar to & for *'and'*? Also, for *'without'*?

Comment: "Most likely historic?" What if it definitely is historic, or definitely isn't historic? Would it still be an answer?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*&* comes from a Latin scribal abbreviation for *et* (*⁊* which was used as an alternative to *&* in Old English and is still used that way in Modern Irish comes from a different form of the same thing).

*c̄* was a Latin scribal abbreviation for *cum* and *p̱* for *per*, both of which would be used some places where in English we would use *with*. They had other meanings too, depending on position within a text.

I do not know of their ever seeing extensive use in English. Update: See the comment below about doctors using it in writing prescriptions.

In modern English there is the slash-abbreviation *w/* for *with*. Around the middle of the last century it was common to write two-letter abbreviations with a slash between those two letters, and *w/o* was so-used for *without* and by extension removing the *o* gives *w/* for *with*.

While it is now rare to use a slash in an abbreviation in this way (unless the expanded from has a slash, like *i/o* for *input/output*), both *w/* and *w/o* continue to enjoy some use.

Comment: Certainly there were a zillion of these. See both [Scribal Abbreviation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scribal_abbreviation) on Wikipedia and Alpo Honkapahja’s [Manuscript abbreviations in Latin and English: History, typologies, and how to handle them in encoding](http://www.helsinki.fi/varieng/series/volumes/14/honkapohja/).

Comment: Medical doctors still use c̄ pretty often, or at least back when they still tended to write prescriptions out by hand.

Comment: The slash in abbreviations is used in French, particularly for the word _sur_ in city names on road signs (for instance _Chalon s/ Saône_  http://i.imgur.com/rAUxAFP.png)